tengo un error en html en donde no me toma el signo '$'
estoy haciendo una pagina web para la universidad con html y JavaScrips, tengo que hacer una función validación y que si el usuario se registra con éxito lo manda un instagram, no estoy usando base datos, solo que ingrese datos con el largo y tipo correcto.
esta seria mi función:
$(function(){ 
    $("#mis-datos").validate({ 
        rules:{
            nombre:{
                required: true
            },
            correo:{
                required: true,
                email:true

              /// el resto 
    })

    $("#botonLogin").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if ($("#mis-datos").valid()) {
        window.location.href = 'https://www.instagram.com/chinisimanails/';
    }
    });
}); ```

y mis scrips en html:

    ```<script src="JavaScript/Login.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryvalidate/1.19.5/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>``` 

todo esto basado en un formulario:
```  <form id="mis-datos">
                <label for="nombre">Nombre:  </label> <br>
                <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Digite su nombre.."
                    class="form-control" minlength="3" required> <br>
                
                <label for="correo">Correo electronico:  </label> <br>
                <input type="email" id="correo" name="correo" placeholder="Digite su correo.."
                        class="form-control" required>  <br>
               
                  /// el resto
  
                
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="botonLogin">Registrar</button>   
                <button id= Cancelar class="btn btn-primary">Cancelar</button>         
            </form> ``` 
ya no se que hacer, seria de gran ayuda ver si pueden ver un error :c


El orden de los script importa. Esto <script src="JavaScript/Login.js"> debe ser tu último script en cargar

muchas graciaaaas, lo cambie y ahora si funciona.

¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? Varios errores de archivos vinculados en header y footer aqui hay una explicacion de como se deben colocar los archivos asociados dentro del html.

Lo que está ocurriendo con tu página es que primero se llama al JavaScript y luego se está cargando el documento HTML después del script.
<script src="JavaScript/Login.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryvalidate/1.19.5/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

En este caso, al utilizar jQuery, se está cargando todo su código antes de que se forme la página HTML. Pero cuando se especifica que cualquier acción programada en JavaScript que cause un efecto en HTML se coloque antes de que se cargue la página, no sucederá nada.
Para corregirlo, utiliza el atributo defer en la tag <script> correspondiente al código programado en JavaScript. El script se ejecutará después de que se haya cargado el HTML y no bloqueará la carga de la página.
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" defer></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.5/jquery.validate.js" defer></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" defer></script>
<script src="JavaScript/Login.js" defer></script>

Con esta nueva estructura, los scripts de jQuery se cargarán y debajo de ellos, el script que programaste en JavaScript se retrasará hasta que el análisis del HTML esté completo.
